# When I try to register for an account on my website, I am returned with the error "Plan must exist"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

After submitting an email and password through my RoR site, I am prompted with an error message stating that

"the plan doesn't exist. "

User Class

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :plan

 attr_accessor :stripe_card_token
  def save_with_subscription
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  end
end
```

Contacts Controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
            # Get request to /contact-us
            # show new contact form
            def new
                @contact = Contact.new
            end


            # Post request /contacts
            def create
            # Mass assignment of form fields into Contact object
               @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
               # save the Contact object to the database
               if @contact.save 
                   # Store form fields via parameters. into variables
                   name = params[:contact][:name]
                   email = params[:contact][:email]
                   body = params[:contact][:comments]
                   # Plug variables into Contact Mailer email method and send email
                   ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
                   # Store success message in flash hash
                   # redirect to the new action
                   flash[:success] = "Message sent."
                    redirect_to new_contact_path
                else
                    # If Contact object doesnt save,
                    # store errors in a flash hash
                    # and redirect to the new action
                    flash[:danger] = @contact.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
                    redirect_to new_contact_path
               end
            end

            private
              # To collect data from form, we need to use
              # strong parameters and whitelist the form fields
                def contact_params
                    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
                end
        end
```

Registrations

```
 class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do |resource|
      if params[:plan]
        resource.plan_id = params[:plan]
        if resource.plan_id == 2
          resource.save_with_subscription
        else
          resource.save
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Basic Form

```
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am unsure what else I may need to add. I am doing the upskill course for fun. Before adding the plans ids using the stripe plugin I was able to create an account just fine. I tried searching around on stackoverflow for a solution, but nothing came about. I am kindof at a dead end and cannot proceed until I finish this part out. The premium subscription part of my site also does not work, but that can be fixed after I do this.

If anyone has any reccomendations on what I can do to fix this it would be greatly appriciated, or what files I will add in order for you to reach your answer.

Thank you.

plan.rb

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

Comment: I may be mistaken here, but I'm not sure that the most recent version of Stripe's API allows you to create a customer with a plan like that. They expect a subscription to be created and a customer to be assigned to that subscription.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
```

Seems like the `plan_id` you are sending doesn't exist on Stripe.

Have you created those plans on stripe?

Comment: I have created both plans on stripe.  I have a "Pro" plan with an ID of 2, and a "Basic" plan with an ID of 1           Thank you for your reply btw!

Comment: And do you have the same in user model because you have belongs_to association

Comment: I will add my plan.rb file above. I apologize but I am not quite too sure what you are asking. I apologize, I am fairly new